# Python regex with parenthesis and decimal place

Tags: regex, python-2.7, format, decimal, parentheses

I'm looking into a complex regex in `Python 2.7` to read the following format from a file. The lines (read as a string) look like this:

```
 line = 23.3(14) 600(3)   760.35(10)
```

The final desired output would be a list (or other) that parses the line as:

```
list = 23.3 1.4 600 3 760.35 0.10 ; list[0]=23.3, list[1]=1.4 ....
```

The regex should read the number between the `()` but also count the number of digits in the number preceding it (immediate left) to correctly interpret the value between `()`.

**Example**: 23.3 has 1 digit after the decimal place, so 14 between the next `()`
would read 1.4 = 14/10. If 23.30 then 0.14=14/100.

Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks guys.

Comment: Regular expressions can't count nor divide numbers, they match text. You can use a regex to match your numbers and then write a Python function to determine the number of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @ Tim: thanks for the feedback. Do you have a suggestion for the regex or function part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could as well go for:

```
import re

line = "23.3(14) 600(3)   760.35(10)"

# split the items
rx = re.compile(r"\d[\d().]+")
digits = rx.findall(line)

# determine the length
def countandsplit(x):
    ''' Finds the length and returns new values'''
    a = x.find('(')
    b = x.find('.')
    if a != -1 and b != -1:
        length = a-b-1
    else:
        length = 0

    parts = list(filter(None, re.split(r'[()]', x)))
    number1 = float(parts[0])
    number2 = round(float(parts[1]) * 10 ** -length, length)
    return [number1, number2]

# loop over the digits
result = [x for d in digits for x in countandsplit(d)]
print(result)
# [23.3, 1.4, 600.0, 3.0, 760.35, 0.1]
```

---

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/HFkVFn).

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
import re
s = "23.3(14) 600(3)   760.35(10)"

def digits(s):                # return the number of digits after the decimal point
    pos = s.find(".")
    if pos == -1:             # no decimal point
        return 0
    else:
        return len(s)-pos-1   # remember that indices are counted from 0

matches = re.findall(r"([\d.]+)\((\d+)\)", s) # find all number pairs
l = []
for match in matches:
    d = digits(match[0])
    if d:                     # More than 0 digits?
        l.append((float(match[0]), float(match[1]) / 10**d))
    else:                     # or just integers?
        l.append((int(match[0]), int(match[1])))
```

The resulting `l` is `[(23.3, 1.4), (600, 3), (760.35, 0.1)]`

Comment: @ Tim: works just perfect as well. I only had a slight preference for the list format for further procesing.